# XCODE not installing pods

Tags: ruby, cocoapods, homebrew, homebrew-cask, cocoapods-1.1.1

i am trying to install pod in my project and getting the error

> `GoogleAppMeasurement` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.10.2`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.10.1`.

i tried with the brew and it gives me this error:

```
The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

Does anyone has a solution for this i am stucking in it for a long time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am trying to install pods in my project and getting error that it needs cocoapods version 1.10.2, then i try to update my pods and it gave me message that you cannot update it because you don't have permission. then i found that you can update it using brew and I did it with brew and it is giving me the error which is written upwards